# Should Mongo concurrency issues be handled using Mongo functionality or a locking module?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, mongoose

In our mean stack application we have started running into concurrency issues in Mongo DB. Things like operations which affect array indices, as well as concurrent updates to subdocuments. We are trying to decide if it is better to use a locking node module such as rwlock to handle these problems, or to leverage the functionality provided by mongo and mongoose. I should note that the issues so far are not related to performance, but are unwanted behavior in the database.

Example: we have A route that contains an ID and a field name, and the body is a json object which will be the value for the field specified. The objects are stored in an array, and if no object with the ID is present, one will be created.

/:id/:field

In the case where we have two posts to the same object ID when that object does not yet exist, both posts will create the object, and the array will end up containing two objects, each with one field set, where it should contain one object with two fields set.

One of the reasons I am hesitating to use the database functionality (Such as the __v field) is that it requires that we use methods which bypass the mongoose middleware, and middleware is one of the reasons we chose mongoose in the first place.

I'm wondering if there are any hidden/obvious pros and cons to using one of these approaches over the other?

Comment: one way is to use sharding, but can you provide example, what command is the bottleneck? do you use indexing?

Comment: Can you use atomic(-ish) operations like `update` or `findAndModify` (and their Mongoose equivalent)?

Comment: @robertklep many of those methods unfortunately do not have Mongoose equivalents. I'm also concerned that code it might be hard to follow/read if we "mix and match" between mongo and mongoose. But perhaps that is not a problem, just something that has come to mind when making this decision

Comment: @PunDefeated `findAndModify` is used by Mongoose for `findOneAndRemove`, `findOneAndUpdate`, and `findByIdAnd*`. If you search [the API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) for `findAndModify` you'll find them.

Comment: @robertklep my bad, I miss spoke. I meant to say that those methods do not use the middleware, but if we have to that is a sacrifice we are willing to make.

Comment: @vdj4y added an example